# Best way to start SSIS catalog or SSIS package remotely

Tags: sql, ssis, package, catalog

I need to execute an SSIS package or an SSIS catalog remotely. What is the best way to acomplish this?

I'm using:

Visual Studio 2012
SQL Server 2012

Comment: Project deployment model (new & default in 2012) or Package deployment model (classic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am almost positive you need an integration server to accomplish this. The package is stored in the MSBD of the integration server and called by job or execution statement from within your code.

Siting MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. you can create integration services catalog and host your project and packages inside it.
2. Now you can navigate to the package and execute it manually by providing all necessary parameters if any.
3. you can call the package by using an in-built stored proc "ssisdb.catalog.create_execution " and provide all necessary input and output parameters.